# how to do a cumulative array search in elasticsearch?

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, hashtag, fuzzy-search

I want to employ hashtag searching in combination with the standard text search.

Here is the kind of query I wish to be able to make:

"leather trousers #vintage #london"

So in effect I am wanting to strip off the #hashtaged elements and search for them by name, in a cumulative sense. Firstly I  want it to prioritise on an exact match via the search string, then to ones with near match + hashtags, then lastly if no match with search string, via the hash tags.

So items with both Vintage and London would be placed higher than ones with either Vintage or London.

Here is my mapping

```
{
  "title" : {   
     "type" : "string",
     "analyzer" : "standard"
     },
  "hashtags" : {
     "properties" : {
          "id" : "integer",
          "name" : "string"
       }
     }
}
```

So the query I want to make is

```
"exact or near match string" + "optional cumulative array match (preferably with fuzzyness)"
```

or in relation to my mapping

```
"near or exact match on 'title'" + "cumulative array match with fizzyness on hashtag.name"
```

I've tried a fuzzy match but get back too much results with not enough clarity.  I've tried a simple simple_query_string but it returns weird results, and tried a bool match but get back nothing when I add the array.

Any help anyone can offer will be more than gratefully accepted.  Let me know if you need more info or whatever?  Many thanks in advance for your time to have even read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe a "dis_max" query can work for you. it enable to make multiples differents queries and concat the results. So her it make a first queries where "hashtags = 'vintage london'" then "hashtags = 'vintage'" then "hashtags = 'london'". you can also add wildcards (`*`) in the researched data like "hashtags = 'london`*`'"

```
{
"fields" : ["hashtags", "title"],
"query" : {
    "dis_max" : {
        "tie_breaker" : 0,

        "queries" : [ {
                "wildcard" : {
                    "hashtags" : "vintage london"
                }
            }, {
                "wildcard" : {
                    "hashtags" : "vintage"
                }
            }, {
                "wildcard" : {
                    "hashtags" : "london"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"sort" : {
    "_score" : "desc"
}   }
```